# Representation of fixed point number in systemverilog

Tags: system-verilog

How should I represent a fixed point number in systemverilog since it doesnt support fixed point numbers for reg and logic.Is using real data type the correct method or can we use any different data type?
I am trying to do a square root function in systemverilog, in which the result will be in FP e.g sqrt(8) = 2.82.
What should be the data type of my inputs and outputs(sqrt) such that I can check the decimal point places correctly while verifying.

Comment: Do you want this code to be synthesizable?

Comment: Yes, it should be synthesizable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use integral types for fixed point numbers. Some people will index their variables like

```
logic [M-1:-F] fp_number; // M-bits integer, F bit fractional
```

But it is up to you to adjust the decimal point when adding different sized numbers as well as adjusting for multiplication and division. There are some OpenCore libraries that have many of these operations for you.